# category/product not reindexed after product save

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using Magento CE 1.7
When I edit a product and add it to a category and save it, the category/product index is not reindexed. So the product is not showing up in a custom block i made.
When I manually refresh the index, the product shows.
However if a edit a product already in the category and remove it from the category, the reindexing happens automatically.

What could be the cause of this behaviour. I'm I correct in assuming the reindexing is supposed to happen automatically on product save.

(reindexing is off course set to happen on save)

Answer (score 0):

No. Reindex will not happen automatically on Category Edit or Save. Every time you have to do it manually only. By default it is of this functionality only. As of my knowledge, If it starts automatically reindexing on edit or save of every category it will consume more time. 
Suppose if you edit Category 1 and you do reindex and edit category 2 and again reindex and edit category 3 and again reindex, then you can check how much time it consumes time for reindexing.

If it is like once you edit category 1, category 2 and category 3 then you made a reindex, then you can check the time it consumes. This is why because the indexing functionality is designed. I think you magento is working fine in reindexing.